# Form background color is still blank even when applying resource

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-form

I use a theme in a resource editor file inside the src folder to set a form's background color, but in runtime the form's background color is still blank ! Here is code :

```
public class Saisie extends Form implements ActionListener {
...
public Resources r;
public Hashtable tTheme;
...
public Saisie(MIDlet midlet)
{
    super("Saisie situation");
try {
        r = Resources.open("/resources.res");
        tTheme = r.getTheme("Theme");
        UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(tTheme);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    ...
}
...
}
```

Comment: Do you define all modes in editor for form? maybe tou define a=only to selected mode and no to unSelecteMode?

Comment: yes I set it for unselected and selected tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you set the bg transparency to 255. If you are making this change after creating the form make sure to refresh it.

Comment: Is it inside the resource editor that I set the bg transparency or in my code ?